# Is there a way to FAKE inheritance in C#/VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-2.0

Suppose I want to inherit from `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction` which is **sealed**. Supose I want to just put a wrapper around `SqlTransaction` and always use `MyTransaction` instead of `SqlTransaction`. Is there a way I could potentially cast `MyTransaction` to `SqlTransaction` using an Implicit/Widening operator?

Comment: `Suppose I want to inherit from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction` => why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: Darin is right; you're asking for a drill rather than telling us about why you need a hole in that steel girder in the first place. The fact that the type is sealed is a big red flag that says I DON'T WANT YOU TO INHERIT FROM THIS. Why are you trying to work against the wishes of the designer of the class? They have your best interests at heart. Explain what you really want to accomplish, because inheriting from a sealed class isn't going to happen.

Comment: Isn't it possible to unseal a class using reflection?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Some non-editable code might *require* the use of the `SqlTransaction` type. Never run into in this case (and it would be interesting to hear the full story), but `ByteBuffer` in Java has a similar "issue". :(

Comment: Wanted to wrap a transaction because I wanted to track who created it, make it raise an event when committed, and a bunch of other custom stuff that I want to track like how long the transaction was open, etc. That SqlTransaction doesn't have.

Comment: Where is this tracking to be done?  Client side?  Server side?  How will you be researching these transactions?  Seems to me some of the custom connection string attributes (machine name, app name, etc) could be set on the connection and visible via SQL.  Hmm... is this a web app, not a thick client?

Comment: This CAN make sense in case one wants to ahve transaction logging in a cleint side logging file ;) That is basically what I read out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want implicit conversion (although I would not recommend it, as it is a horrible idea and a horrible design, IMO), you can do something like this:

```
    class MyTransaction
    {
        private readonly SqlTransaction _transaction;

        public MyTransaction(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            _transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public SqlTransaction Transaction
        {
            get
            {
                return _transaction;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator SqlTransaction(MyTransaction t)
        {
            return t.Transaction;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is in VB.NET and their Widening operator doesn't seem to work as C#'s "implicit" is what I just found out but was thinking about this route also... Although like you said I don't like it either...

Comment: @Denis you could try coding the class in C# and then use the DLL in your VB app

Comment: @Denis Code in C#, use Refelctor to disassemble in VB and you see the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a class that has an inner transaction variable and then expose the methods and properties. Kind of like this:

```
public class MyTransaction
{
    System.Data.SqlTransaction myTx = someConnection.CreateTransaction();

    public void CommitTransaction() :  {
        myTx.CommitTransaction()
    }
}
```

You could also make it inherit from DbTransaction and then rewrite the abstract and virtual procedures to use the inner myTx variable, but it starts getting a little complex for no apparent real reason...

Comment: Absolutely! :-Þ  But if the man wants to wrap a transaction, there may be a reason!

Comment: Just because he wants to do it, and even if its possible, doesn't mean he should.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, but still it's a good way to learn for other -more suitable- cases where a solution like this is suitable

Answer (score 3):

If you are just interested in adding additional methods to a class you could use extension methods.  That won't give you access to any internal state, or allow you to override behaviors, but it will let you add limited functionality.  I'm not aware of any way to inherit from a sealed class.

You could create a true wrapper object as others have mentioned, but you won't be able to use it polymorphically in place of the original object.

Comment: This is in .NET 2.0 so no extension methods... But I also need to keep track of stuff since creation so extensions methods won't work anyway.

Comment: Not that this matters because of the .net 2 thing, but extension methods can track independent object data using a dictionary keyed off the first parameter of the extension method (the object being manipulated).  This can offer a "partitioned" set of data that resembles internal state but is stored external to the object.  Internal members can be accessed via reflection, so you can do some interesting things depending on how "ugly" you are willing to let the code get.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added a .net2.0 tag to your question so others know the framework version is limited.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so ruling out the inheritance and focusing on the task you really want to solve (based on the comment threads).

I have had success in the past running all calls through a helper library and implementing the logic there.  In the past, I have used SqlHelper, which is published in the Microsoft [Data Application Block](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=435).   This is a source module, which you can adapt to your needs.  You can add whatever logging or other logic you require.

It also makes the code very readable.  You can do things like:

`SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset()` for queries returning sets of data,

`SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar()` for queries returning single values,

`SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery()` for commands which have no returns (like `INSERT`'s).

etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have your custom class be inherited from SqlTransaction or to have this faked.

However, if the context of what you are doing allows you to use a DbTransaction, you could inherit your custom transaction class from DbTransaction, wrapping up a SqlTransaction inside with whatever other functionality you require.

Comment: I thought this would work also but then you have something like SqlClient.SQLCommand.Transaction which wants SqlTransaction

Comment: Yeah, you get into a whole ratsnest of wrapped objects... you could use all custom wrapper from the System.Data namespace wrapping SQL versions.... it all depends on what your requirements are and why you are messing with these objects in the first place.  There are likely other (better) ways to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You do have another option, you could use Reflection.Emit() to add an interface of your choosing to SqlTransaction, and then use that same interface, in your new MyTransaction class and then you can make calls to the interface, instead of the class.

Take care that this will only work within libraries you create, or specifically modify the loaded types using Reflection.

Comment: I have never tried Reflection.Emit(). I am going to look around but do you have any good examples/tutorials on how this would work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension methods.

```
public static class SqlTransactionExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this SqlTransaction transaction, int myParameter)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

The class must be static. Place the magic word `this` in front of the fist parameter which must be of the type of the class you are extending. You can extend interfaces as well. If you want to use this extension method, then you must have a `using namspace` with the namespace of this extension class, if it is not defined in the same namespace you are working in.

You can then call the extension method as if it was a regular method of SqlTransaction:

```
SqlTransaction t = new SqlTransaction();
t.DoSomething(5);
```

Comment: This is a good idea someone proposed here also but there are 2 problems with this: (1) I am using .NET 2.0 and (2) If I wasn't using .NET 2.0 how would I use Extension methods to create objects at creation of SqlTransaction? (let's say I want to track who created this sqlTransaction or the time when it was started)

Comment: I would create a static helper class for transactions. Very much like the extensions class, but without the `this` keyword. Instead of calling the methods with `t.DoSomething(5);`, you will have to call them with `TransactionsHelper.DoSomething(t, 5);`. Extension methods are really just syntactical sugar and they cannot do anything that could not be done with normal methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own MyTransaction class as a wrapper around SqlTransaction. Keep an instance of SqlTransaction in a private field inside MyTransaction. Your wrapper will not be assignment compatible with SqlTransaction, but if you implement the same interfaces SqlTransaction implements you can get pretty close.

Comment: I thought this would work also but then you have something like SqlClient.SQLCommand.Transaction which wants SqlTransaction, not IDbTransaction which really sux so I need some way to fake this which started this quest...